# 'Ihr lernt deutsch' or 'sie lernt deutsch'

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice, german-to-english

I know that some parts of the sentence can change but what I mean is: **ihr** is **es**, and I had seen that **ich gehe es gut** is wrong and the right is **mir geht es gut**, so in that situation is the same logic?

If yes, why in this case the **es** is in Dativ form but not in Nominativ form?

PS: Please, don't answer it as "One is right", describe it more to know why it is right, please.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you think "ihr lernt Deutsch" could be correct. 'Sie' is the one learning German so 'sie' should be in the nominative, not dative.

Comment: It is because I had seen this sentence in Google Translate, I know Google Translate is not good to learn but I had already made a question asking which of the two sentences is right, the people said the right is 'Mir geht es gut'

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to translate, so could you please edit your post and add the English sentence?

Comment: And could you please clarify what you mean with "ihr is es"? Maybe add a link or an example.

Comment: Take a look at this table: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Pers.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, "es" is the *nominative* form of the pronoun meaning "it". The dative form of "ihr" ("you", as in several people) would be "euch". "ihr" can also be the dative form of "sie" ("she"). I think you are confusing the two meanings of "ihr". Your examples are both grammatically correct, but they have different meaning:

> "Ihr lernt deutsch." = "You learn German."

Here "ihr" is the second person plural pronoun meaning "you" (several people) and *not* the dative form of "sie" ("she").

> "Sie lernt deutsch." = "She learns German."

In both of these cases, "ihr" and "sie" are in *nominative case* because they are the subject of the sentence, identifiable by the question "Who is learning German?".

---

Understanding how "I am fine" translates to "Mir geht es gut" (or just "Mir geht's gut") can be somewhat difficult. In English, the verb ("am") is conjugated based on the person being fine ("I"), but this is not the case in German.

In this context, the verb "gehen" is what is called an *impersonal verb*, meaning that it has a dummy subject after which the verb is conjugated. An example of an impersonal verb in English is

> "**It** is snowing"

Here the pronoun "it" carries no real meaning, and "snowing" is therefore an impersonal verb.

We can see how this relates to our German sentence if we instead translate

> "Mir geht **es** gut."

as

> "**It** is going well for me."

We see that the subject of the sentence is actually "it". This means that "me" will receive either accusative or dative case since it is an *object* of the sentence. Deciding between accusative and dative can be rather difficult, and the most truthful answer is simply that you have to memorize that a lot of impersonal verbs take dative case, for example:

> "Es gefällt **mir**." = "I like it."
>
> "Es tut **mir** leid." = "I am sorry."
>
> "Es schmeckt **mir**." = "It tastes well (to me)."

A clue that the case is dative might be that it is "*for* me" in the sentence since a rule of thumb is that objects which answer the question "For/to whom?" receive dative case.

Answer (score 2):

Constructions with *es* like

> Es geht mir gut.

are very special. Also *gehen* can be pretty confusing in its different kind of meanings and usage. So it's not a good idea to compare other phrases to that one.

If you mean (ihr is es) *ihr* is subject like *es* and therefor should be nominative, you're right. And actually it is nominative.

The *ihr* in

> Ihr lernt deutsch.

is not dative (or genitive) of *sie* in

> Sie lernt deutsch.

Instead *ihr* is second person plural pronoun here. Therefor you find both sentences and both are right but have different meanings.